# make from within subdirectory of project

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu

**Is there a way to run "make" from within a subdirectory of my project, with a makefile at its root?**

In the same way that git will look for a .git folder in the current directory, and if it doesn't exist there, will check up one directory, etc... until it either finds a git repo or reaches the system root, I'd like to be able to have make look upwards for a makefile. Is this possible?

One solution would be to have a makefile in every directory that simply calls make in the directory above it... but that seems like an unnecessary amount of files and is very prone to error (forgetting to put it in a directory, etc...). Plus, I'd like to be able to send arguments to make (ie 'make this.file' or 'make clean'), and I'm not sure that'd be possible with this method...

I hope this is on the correct stackexchange site. Sorry if it isn't! And thanks for reading/answering!

Comment: No, there is no way to get make to automatically look for makefiles in parent directories.  Well, you could change the code of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to implement something like this. The following worked for me in the past:

- At the *top* of the project I have files `config.mk` and `Makefile`. The latter defines a variable `TOP` as top project directory.
- In each relevant subdirectory there is a `Makefile` that has the following directives:

  ```
    TOP ?= ../..

    include $(TOP)/config.mk
  ```

This is not a perfect solution but it allows significant reuse of make logic and both full and partial rebuilds.

Comment: Darn. Unfortunate that this is the best option. However, I didn't even know that make could include things, so that's a start. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if anyone cares, but adding makefiles in subdirectories was really obnoxious, so I just went ahead and wrote a simple bash script that wraps make into my intended functionality - https://github.com/Phildo/anywhere-make